# Convert array to a Map of array index to value

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, intstream

What's wrong with this code?

```
int[] nums = new int[] {8, 3, 4};
Map<Integer,Integer> val2Idx = 
    IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(idx -> idx, idx -> nums[idx]));
```

I'm hoping to produce a `Map` with these values:

```
{0=8, 1=3, 2=4}
```

But the error is

> method collect in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to box the `int`s to `Integer`s:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> val2Idx =
    IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
             .boxed() // Here!
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(idx -> idx, idx -> nums[idx]));
```

Comment: Just to add some rationale: main problem is that `IntStream` doesn't *have* method like `collect(Collector)` but **only** `collect​(Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,​R> combiner)` so `Collectors.toMap` isn't treated as proper argument so it doesn't even have a chance to infer that `idx` is `int`. Simple fix is to use `Stream` version which has that method and can be easily created as shown in the answer.

Comment: Alternative fix would be providing all 3 required parameters like `.collect( HashMap::new, (map, index) -> map.put(index, nums[index]), (mainMap, otherMap) -> mainMap.putAll(otherMap) );`

Answer (score 1):

[`IntStream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) requires three arguments; if you want to use the 2-argument version, you must use [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) to convert it to a `Stream<Integer>`.

```
int[] nums = new int[] {8, 3, 4};
Map<Integer,Integer> val2Idx = 
    IntStream.range(0, nums.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(idx -> idx, idx -> nums[idx]));
System.out.println(val2Idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

This erros it's because of the `idx` the it's a object and not a int